# Преобразование массива типа int в тип char C#

Tags: c#, массивы, char

Вообщем, столкнулся с проблемой: хочу составить маленькую программу, в которой пользователь вводит любое целое число и ему на экран выводится длина этого числа,т.е. количество цифр из которых состоит это число.Только есть один нюанс: переменная, в которую мы заносим наше число, должна быть типа int. Так вот, мне надо ввести это число, преобразовать его массив типа char и вывести на экран длину числа.

Comment: Есть метод toString().

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Для этого даже хранить число не надо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас есть массив целых чисел (или отдельное целое число), то вывести длины символьных представлений чисел достаточно просто, Например,

```
int[] a = { 10, 5, 543, 87654 };

foreach (int x in a) Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x, x.ToString().Length);
```

Вывод этого фрагмента кода будет следующим

```
10: 2
5: 1
543: 3
87654: 5
```

Единственная проблема - это когда число отрицательное. В этом случае вы должны проверять, является ли оно меньше нуля, и если является, то вычитать единицу из выражения `x.ToString().Length`.

Comment: Или `Math.Abs(x).ToString().Length`